# Parameter to lambda expression query

Tags: c#

```
public void display()
{
    var Charts = chartGroup.Descendants("charts").Elements("chart")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "4")
        .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
}
```

I had written following lambda expression. As of now this works fine. But I want to set search value as user parameter ..something like

```
public void display(int userid)
{
    var Charts = chartGroup.Descendants("charts").Elements("chart")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == userid)
        .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
}
```

But it gives error.
Please help out how to solve this?

Comment: How many guesses of the error do I get?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing an int and a string makes no sense:

```
public void display(int userid) {
 var Charts = chartGroup.Descendants("charts")
                        .Elements("chart")
                        .Where(x =>  x.Attribute("id").Value == userid.ToString())
                        .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search pattern has to be **string** but you are passing as **int**. So convert it **ToString()** .

```
 var Charts = 
            chartGroup.Descendants("charts").Elements("chart").
            Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == userid.ToString()).
            Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
```